# Compute the what was added or remove from new and original array

Tags: javascript

this seems pretty silly to ask but I'm moving a bit away from PHP to javascript and have a bit of a hard time with 2 arrays one the original values and the other the new values.

I need to take take action on any values removed (run some function) and on any *new* values that where added.

Here is what I came up with so far, but it doesn't seem right.

```
// new values
var array1 = [ 'aaaa', 'R26i9vjDHE', 'bbbbb' ];
// original values
var array2 = [ 'U8G5AQVsX6', 'R26i9vjDHE', '7IkuofIHEu','aaaa'];

for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if(array1.indexOf(array2[i]) != -1) {
    console.log('in new already?');
    console.log(array2[i])
    // do something with new inserted value
  } else {
    console.log('removed items');
    console.log(array2[i])
    // do something with a removed value
  }  
}
```

I'm used to php's in_array in a loop or various other php tool box items.

Suggestions?

my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xv8ah2yf/8/

Comment: *"it doesn't seem right"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement. Demo is missing a comma in one array. Please make sure to check browser console for errors

Comment: You may of caught me in the middle of editing my comment and the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So an element that was removed will be in `array2`, but not `array1`, and then an element added will be in `array1` but not `array2`. So to detect both cases you'll need to loop through both arrays. You can do something like

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array1.indexOf(array2[i]) === -1) {
        //item removed from array2
        console.log(array2[i] + ' removed');
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array2.indexOf(array1[i]) === -1) {
        //item added to array1
        console.log(array1[i] + ' added');
    }
}
```

Then take the appropriate action when each case is detected.

Comment: So this is actually what I ended up with.. Minus any functions I want to call.. here is the fiddle, but yea pretty spot on. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLwz9t0c/) .. Are their any draw backs to this because it seems like this can be done in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just define what is meant be "added" and "removed":

- added: in `new` array but *not* in `original`.
- removed: in `original` but *not* in `new` array.

We can use 2 for-loops to determine these two types of elements:

```js
let original_array = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
let new_array      = ['def', 'jkl', 'mno'];
for (let i = 0; i < new_array.length; i++){
    if (!original_array.includes(new_array[i])){
        console.log(new_array[i], 'has been added');
        //further actions...
    }
}
for (let i = 0; i < original_array.length; i++){
    if (!new_array.includes(original_array[i])){
        console.log(original_array[i], 'has been removed');
        //further actions...
    }
}
```

Comment: seems close to the one above which I ended up adding to the code.  I realize their are plenty of ways to do things in codeing, I'm just wrapping my head around some stuff in JS.  Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function compute(original, modified, addedCB, removedCB) {
  for (let i of modified) {
    if (!original.includes(i)) {
        // this is a new value
      addedCB(i);
    }
  }
  for (let i of original) {
    if (!modified.includes(i)) {
        // the modified array doesn't include this value
      removedCB(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, seem a bit more than i needed at first, how is data returned from this function..

Comment: The function doesn't directly return data.The data is returned through callbacks. You'd call it with two other functions. Let's say you had a `function added(item) { console.log(item + ' added') }` and `function removed(item) { console.log(item + ' removed') }`, you'd call compute like this: `compute(array1, array2, added, removed)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to PHP's `in_array` with javascript's [`array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). You can use that to then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the arrays in question:

This is a little slower than doing everything in a `for` loop, but also more succinct and cleared (IMO):

```js
// new values
var array1 = [ 'aaaa', 'R26i9vjDHE', 'bbbbb' ];
// original values
var array2 = [ 'U8G5AQVsX6', 'R26i9vjDHE', '7IkuofIHEu','aaaa'];

// in array1 but not in array2
let not_in_array2 = array1.filter(item => !array2.includes(item))

// in array2 but not in array1
let not_in_array1 = array2.filter(item => !array1.includes(item))

// in both arrays
let inBoth = array1.filter(item => array2.includes(item))

console.log("Not in array1:", not_in_array1)
console.log("Not in array2:", not_in_array2)
console.log("In both:", inBoth)
```

From there you can `forEach()` or `map()` over the results and apply whatever function you want.

Comment: Interesting, from all the past programming I'm usually looping though unless the function has its own call back.  When you say slower, do you mean just in processing the data, so slower than running quickly though a for loop?

Comment: I would take 'slower' with a grain of salt unless you are processing a lot and notice a bottleneck. It's slower because your looping through the array with each call to `filter()` — so you do it twice as apposed to looping through once. And `for` loops are really well optimized in most javascript implementations, so they will often beat other functional methods in test — but again, that's only important if it effects real-world performance. I really like this functional style of javascript, but of course that's just my opinion.